# How to access ref of child component with wrappers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, react-forwardref

I'm trying to learn how `forwardRef` works in React and playing around with it based on official docs. I understand how it works with this basic example:

```
import { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react"

const ChildComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showAlert() {
      alert("Hello from Child Component")
    },
  }))
  return <div></div>
})

function App() {
  const childCompRef = useRef()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => childCompRef.current.showAlert()}>Click Me</button>
      <ChildComp ref={childCompRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

When I click the button in `App`, it shows the alert, so far so good.

However based on my real use case, I have to do bunch of wrappings on top of my `ChildComp`, which could be simplified as the following. Here is the [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-9d6hy8?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
const getWrapper = () => {
  return class Test extends Component{
    public render() {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
}

const withWrapper = (
  Component: React.FunctionComponent | React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<React.RefAttributes<unknown>>
  ) => {
    function Wrapped(props: any) {
      return React.createElement(getWrapper(), {}, <Component {...props} />)
    }
    return Wrapped;
  }

const ChildComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showAlert() {
      alert("Hello from Child Component!~")
    },
  }))
  return <div></div>
})

const WrappedChild = withWrapper(ChildComp);

function App() {
  const childCompRef = useRef()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => childCompRef.current.showAlert()}>Click Me</button>
      <WrappedChild ref={childCompRef} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

It shows `childCompRef.current` is undefined when I click on the button. The wrappers cannot be removed due to legacy reasons. I'm wondering where in the process does it lose the "ref" and how could I make it work as before in this case? Do I need to wrap `forwardRef` somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You need another layer of `forwardRef`:

```js
const withWrapper = () => {
    return forwardRef((props, ref) => React.createElement(getWrapper(), {}, <Component {...props} ref={ref}/>));
}
```